# Matlab plots coloring area

Tags: matlab-figure

I'm working on this code to get liner power consumption result :

```
P_out = 0:100;   
Po= 130 ;         
dP= 4.7 ;         
N_TRX=6;
P_max= 20;
p_sleep= 75;

if 0< P_out <= P_max
    P = N_TRX*Po+N_TRX*dP*P_out;
else 
   P=N_TRX* p_sleep;
end
%%%%%
Po= 130 ;          
dP= 2.8 ;         
N_TRX=6;
P_max= 40;

if 0< P_out <= P_max
    P1= N_TRX*Po+N_TRX*dP*P_out;
else 
   P1=N_TRX* p_sleep;
end
%%%%%
Po= 130 ;          
dP= 5.9 ;         
N_TRX=2;
P_max= 20;

if 0< P_out <= P_max
    P2= N_TRX*(Po+dP*P_out);
else 
   P_in2=N_TRX* p_sleep;
end
%%%%%
Po= 110 ;          
dP= 4.2;         
N_TRX=6;
P_max= 20;

if 0< P_out <= P_max_macro
    P3= N_TRX*Po+N_TRX*dP*P_out;
else 
   P3=N_TRX* p_sleep;
end

figure, plot(P_out,P,'b'); hold on, plot(P_out,P1,'g'); hold on,      plot(P_out,P2,'r'); hold on,plot (P_out,P3,'y'),hold off
```

The plot is here:

[image: the plot is here]

and I want to fill the area between the lines with colors to get 4 areas colored with its line color.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this using the `area` function:

```
h = area(P_out,[P2;P1-P2;P3-P1;P-P3].');
h(1).FaceColor = 'r';
h(2).FaceColor = 'g';
h(3).FaceColor = 'y';
h(4).FaceColor = 'b';
```

Which will give you this:

[image: fillArea4]

you can also use some nicer colors and transparency:

```
ax = axes;
col = mat2cell(lines(4),ones(4,1),3);
hold on
h(1) = area(ax,P_out,P);
h(4) = area(ax,P_out,P3);
h(2) = area(ax,P_out,P1);
h(3) = area(ax,P_out,P2);
set(h,{'FaceColor'},col)
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.6)
hold off
```

to get this:

[image: fillArea5]